# Asp.Net MVC 5 - Partial-VIew update model in the View who calls the PartialView

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, partial-views

```
public class FichaVM
    {
       public Ficha { get; set; }
       public IList<PergutaVM> PerguntasRespostas { get; set; }
    }

  public class PergutaVM
    {
        public int PerguntaID{ get; set; }
        public string Nome{ get; set; }
       etc....
    }



[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(FichaVM dados)
{
 code...
}
```

// View - ficha_01

```
@model FichaVM

@using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="box-body">

                @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Ficcha.ID)

                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <legend class="scheduler-border">
                        <div class="col-sm-6"  >Dados gerais da ficha</div>
                    </legend>
                    <div style="margin-left:15px;">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Ficha.Nome)
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Ficha.Nome)
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Ficha.Nome)
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        @Html.Partial("_Pergunta", @Model.PerguntasRespostas)


                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="box-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right">Salvar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

// PartialView PerguntasRespostas

```
 @model  IList<PergutaVM> 

    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
    {                     {
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model[i].Nome)
    }
```

My View call a _PartialView with the parameter List
(@Html.Partial("_Pergunta", @Model.PerguntasRespostas))
If I update the model (List) on the PartialView, is possible to update this data( model.PerguntasRespostas) in the View who calls the PartialView?

Comment: Stack Overflow is an English language site. Would you be able to edit your question in English please?

Comment: Alternatively perhaps you'd be more comfortable deleting the question and re-asking it [here](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/)